# Installed Ruby 2.0.0, but an error tells me I have 1.9.3 installed

Tags: ruby, bundler, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.0

I just cloned my Rails app onto my new computer. Ruby 2.0.0 seemed to install with no issue, but when I run `sudo bundle install` inside my app, I get an error telling me I have Ruby 1.9.3 installed:

```
$ sudo bundle install
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

and `bundle install` returns this:

```
$ bundle install
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /usr/bin/bundle:7:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand why I would have `1.9.3` installed. I used the command `rvm install 2.0.0` to install Ruby.

Also, `ruby -v` returns:

```
ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [x86_64-linux]
```

What's going on?

**Output of `rvm list`**

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `rvm list` ?

Comment: @brito I posted it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using rvm, you shouldn't ever need to use `sudo` on any of your commands. Using `sudo` is likely running the globally installed 1.9.3 version.

If you just installed Ruby 2.0.0 and haven't done anything else, then you most likely need to install bundler first before using it:

`gem install bundler`

Once you've done that, `bundle install` (without `sudo`) should work fine.